# Keyboard appears automatically in flutter

Tags: flutter, focus, flutter-layout

how to implement this automatic appearance of key board without tapping the text field in flutter

[image: Text]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
autofocus: true
```

Try this into `TextField`